# Do you have to restart a windows service if you change the app.config?

Tags: .net, windows-services

Do you have to restart a windows service if you change the app.config?

Comment: No you don't have to. Ref link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx

Comment: No : If you have code written to read again from the setting by using configuration Manager.
Yes:  If it does not have additional logic, you have to restart the service.

Answer (score 35):

[Yes, you do](http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2005/02/20/376880.aspx):

> .Net framework will read the app.config once, and never touch the app.config again. That is why you have to restart the application to pick up the change.
>
> Why does not .Net framework detect that app.config has changed, and refresh all the config data?
>
> The reason is simple, this is not possible in general.
>
> Let’s use Raymond’s “imagine this could be done” logic here...

Comment: This was all back in 2005. Surely we've improved things by now?

Answer (score 14):

I've used this before.  Essentially this reloads the specified section before retrieving the value. Quite possibly less efficient than a config file watcher that refreshes on demand, but certainly effective used carefully.

```
  ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
  sValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(name)
```

Comment: That's a great find!

Answer (score 8):

No, you don't *have* to. But if you want for changes in `app.config` to take effect, you might need to restart it. Or you might want to implement a custom configuration file watcher mechanism which would alter services' settings on the fly.

Comment: " if you want for changes in app.config to take effect," - I think that is implicit in the question!

Comment: Great, just when I'm out of rubber chickens.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Presumably you mean the appname.exe.config file?

Answer (score 2):

Usually yes. However you could write a windows service that would put a file monitor on the configuration file and sense a modification and apply it without the need to restart.

For example the Log4Net logging framework offers such a mechanism for its configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

This goes way out of the scope of the question, but I would guess you want to make changes only in some "application-specific" section (appSettings, etc.).

You are better off writing your own config section handler, which monitors it's own config file - the approach [nlog uses](http://www.nlog-project.org/config.html#file). Check the section "**Automatic reconfiguration**".